# NSFetchRequest predicate syntax

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an entity called `Task` in my Core Data model. The `Task` entity has a transformable attribute called `date`. The class of the `date` attribute is a class called `TDate` (which conforms to NSCoding, therefore being a transformable attribute). `TDate` has a property of type `NSInteger` called `month`.

In my `NSFetchRequest` I want to get all `Task` objects of a specific month. I'm using the following predicate:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date.month == 7"]`

That *should* get me all `Task` objects in the month of July. However, with this predicate, no fetched objects are returned. I can confirm that there are `Task` objects whos month is 7 (July) by taking out the predicate. Is there something wrong with my predicate syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an SQLite backend, then you cannot search against transformable properties. On the SQLite backend, the fetch request's predicate is transformed to SQL and executed on the SQLite engine. Because SQLite has no knowledge of Cocoa, predicates that execute against the SQLite backend can't use transformable properties.

If you're using an XML, binary or in-memory store, you can use predicates that query against transformable properties since the entire object graph is in-memory and is queried using native Cocoa.

Comment: I ended up creating separate attributes for each property of the `date` object. Thanks.